# use django-filter with object url_params

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, react-admin

I have successfully implemented django-filter on my Django-rest-framework server.

I have the following filter_class

> filters.py

```
class EmploymentFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = EmploymentCheck
        fields  = ['instructions',]
```

> views.py

```
class EmploymentCheckViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = ContentRangeHeaderPagination
    serializer_class = EmploymentCheckSerializer
    queryset = EmploymentCheck.objects.all()
    filter_class = EmploymentFilter
```

the filter works when i send a get request as

> /employmentcheck/?instructions=2

However, I have implemented a front end with [react-admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Resource.html).
My front-end, sends a request with the url_params as objects

> /employmentcheck/?filter={"instruction_id":"2"}&range=[0,24]&sort=["id","DESC"]/

Notice how the URL specifies a filter object, in which, it defines the parameters to filter against.

My question is, how and where can I filter my model without changing the URL pattern from my client?
Any other advise that spans the scope of my question is equally welcomed

> Models.py

```
class EmploymentCheck(models.Model):
    instructions = models.ForeignKey(Instruction, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply omitted the filter_class, and instead overrode the get_queryset() method of the viewset.

> Allow me to make some changes, the commented out code would fail if you sent a request with no 'filter' query params. e.g GET:/api/employee/ as opposed to GET:/api/employee/?filter{"instruction"=""}

So I opted to check if the query_params.get('key') was none, if so, i pass an empty string.

> Any better pythonic way of handling this is encouraged
>
> ViewSet

```
class EmploymentCheckViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EmploymentCheckSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = EmploymentCheck.objects.all()

        if self.request.query_params.get('filter') is None:
            return queryset #return the queryset as is
        else:
        _instructions = self.request.query_params.get('filter')            #returned as a string
        _instructions = json.loads(_instructions)#convert to dictionary
        if queryset and any(_instructions):
            queryset = queryset.filter(instructions = _instructions['instruction_id'])
            return queryset
```

Note: When you override the get_queryset, you must explicitly define the base_name argument of the router.register method in your app.urls.py. Refer to [django-rest-framework routers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/).

> urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'employmentcheck', views.EmploymentCheckViewSet, 'EmploymentCheck')#explicitly set the base_name attribute when the viewset defines a custom get_queryset method
```